# jquery event handlers on HTML redraw

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have the following HTML and js

```
<div>
  <div class="testdiv" id="test1">test</div>
  <div class="testdiv" id="test2">test</div>
</div>

function DynamicEvents() {

  $('.testdiv').click (function () {
     DoSomething();
  });
}

function RedrawHTML() {

  $('#test1').html('new HTML');
  DynamicEvents();
}
```

Everytime I'm calling `RedrawHTML`, I'm also calling `DynamicEvents` to rebind test1. Suppose I'm calling `RedrawHTML` several times to update the div. My question is this: when I click on test2, does the function `DoSomething()` get executed once or get executed as many times as I've called `RedrawHTML()`?

Comment: Are you missing starting Quotes for **class=testdiv"** or intentionally not inserted? If not, please correct your code.

Comment: @SivaCharan: yes, fixed the quote, thanks.

Comment: Why **DynamicEvents()** is called inside the **RedrawHTML()**? If **RedrawHTML()** is called then obviously you can write the DynamicEvents code inside this function only.

Comment: @SivaCharan: in this example you're right but in my code I have several kinds of functions like RedrawHTML that address different parts of the page and that all need the DynamicEvents to handle the .testdiv handlers when they're redrawn.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to properly use `.on` you need to bind the event(s) to a parent element that is currently present in the DOM. So if i were you i would give the parent div an id and bind the event to that. Here's an example

For your html

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="testdiv" id="test1">test</div>
  <div class="testdiv" id="test2">test</div>
</div>
```

In the JS

```
$('#container').on('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething);
```

If there's no parent element guaranteed to be in the DOM the time the event is bound, then you could in the worst case bind to the `body` or `document` but i do not recommend this approach.

```
$("body").on('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething); 

$(document).on('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething);
```

If you're not using jQuery 1.7, the equivalent delegate code would be

```
 $('#container').delegate('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething);
```

You only need to do this once, all click events triggered by `.testdiv` will bubble up to the `#container` and `DoSomething()` will be executed.

Comment: ok, forget the delegate function; it looks like the on function is newerr/better... If I run the on() function in the document.ready() and the testdiv element is NOT on the page initially (ie. container is empty and the .testdivs get drawn later), will the event be binded when the element is drawn the first time or do I absolutely need to have a .testdiv somewhere on the page when the .on() function runs?

Comment: Frenchie, you don't need to have a .testdiv element present on the page prior to binding the event, you need to have the `#container` element though. Yes the event will be bound for all new .testdiv elements.

Comment: @frenchie - with either `on()` or `delegate()` (in this case, same thing, different syntax), you don't need the child selector to exist when the handler is bound. It's basically a handler on the parent that checks whether the event target matches the child selector.

Comment: I like your example. I changed it a bit to add a delay to show that the binding occurs after the load even when the element is not on the page but it's not working: http://jsfiddle.net/5PWtT/19/

Comment: Stellar! thanks. Btw, what was wrong with the setTimeout('test()', 1000); statement I had?

Comment: As an add-on to your great answer, I added this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/5PWtT/33/ to show that the on() function keeps the event live when you insert HTML, remove it, and then add it again. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

`DoSomething` will be called multiple times when you bind click events multiple times. Instead of rebinding events, use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate) or [`live`](http://api.jquery.com/live) to bind an event handler once and have it catch events on newly inserted DOM elements.

Even better, if you're using jQuery 1.7+, use the `delegate` form of [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on):

```
$(document).on('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething);
```

Comment: If I use this new on function, does this mean that the new HTML doesn't need to be rebound on every redraw?

Comment: `on` is the new catchall for `bind`, `delegate`, and `live`. For devs such as myself who are used to using `bind`, `delegate`, and `live` it'll take some getting used to the new syntax. For new devs it may be confusing as to why you'd need to rebind `$('#foo .bar').on('click', function...)` but not `$('#foo').on('click', '.bar', function...)`

Comment: ok, so if I write $('#test1').on('click', '.testdiv', DoSomething); in my document.ready() function, does this line need to be executed every time I call RedrawHTML or just once and when I call Redraw the event will still be live after the redraw?

Comment: In this code you're saying, whenever a div with class `.testdiv` is clicked let the event bubble up to `#test1`. Doesn't seem to make sense looking at the OP's HTML.

Comment: I think @Interstellar_Coder's right - wouldn't you need the initial selector to reference the containing div, not `#test1`?

Comment: and you'd be correct. I didn't pay attention to the HTML. My mistake. @Interstellar_Coder has the right idea in his answer.

Answer (score 0):

When you call the **`RedrawHTML()`** from a different places, at that time if you have clicked either on **`test1`** or **`test2`** then **`DoSomething();`** will execute.

Comment: yes but my question is how many times will it be called and then a) how do I make it called only once and b) how do I make it called at least once in the case where the element is not on the page on document.load.